# Data mismatch after Kafka JDBC Sink Connector

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Trying to sink data into PostgreSQL using `kafka-connect-jdbc`, but some values inside database are different than kafka message value.

Sink config:

```
{
    "name": "test-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",

        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db?user=test&password=test",
        "dialect.name": "PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect",

        "topics.regex": "test.public.(.*)",

        "transforms": "dropPrefix, unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",

        "transforms.dropPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.regex": "test.public.(.*)",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement": "public.test_$1",

        "auto.create": "true",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_key",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
        "batch.size": "1"
    }
}
```

Message inside kafka topic:

{
"schema": {
"type": "struct",
"fields": [
{
"type": "struct",
"fields": [
{
"type": "int64",
"optional": false,
"field": "id"
},
{
"type": "int64",
"optional": true,
"field": "test_c_id"
},
{
"type": "string",
"optional": true,
"field": "test_b_c"
},
{
"type": "string",
"optional": true,
"field": "test_a_t"
},
{
"type": "array",
"items": {
"type": "string",
"optional": true
},
"optional": true,
"field": "test_p"
},
{
"type": "int64",
"optional": true,
"field": "test_d_id"
}
],
"optional": true,
"name": "test.public.test.Value",
"field": "before"
},
{
"type": "struct",
"fields": [
{
"type": "int64",
"optional": false,
"field": "id"
},
{
"type": "int64",
"optional": true,
"field": "test_c_id"
},
{
"type": "string",
"optional": true,
"field": "test_b_c"
},
{
"type": "string",
"optional": true,
"field": "test_a_t"
},
{
"type": "array",
"items": {
"type": "string",
"optional": true
},
"optional": true,
"field": "test_p"
},
{
"type": "int64",
"optional": true,
"field": "test_d_id"
}
],
"optional": true,
"name": "test.public.test.Value",
"field": "after"
},
{
"type": "struct",
"fields": [
{
"type": "string",
"optional": false,
"field": "version"
},
{
"type": "string",
"optional": false,
"field": "connector"
},
{
"type": "string",
"optional": false,
"field": "name"
},
{
"type": "int64",
"optional": false,
"field": "ts_ms"
},
{
"type": "string",
"optional": true,
"name": "io.debezium.data.Enum",
"version": 1,
"parameters": {
"allowed": "true,last,false"
},
"default": "false",
"field": "snapshot"
},
{
"type": "string",
"optional": false,
"field": "db"
},
{
"type": "string",
"optional": false,
"field": "schema"
},
{
"type": "string",
"optional": false,
"field": "table"
},
{
"type": "int64",
"optional": true,
"field": "txId"
},
{
"type": "int64",
"optional": true,
"field": "lsn"
},
{
"type": "int64",
"optional": true,
"field": "xmin"
}
],
"optional": false,
"name": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source",
"field": "source"
},
{
"type": "string",
"optional": false,
"field": "op"
},
{
"type": "int64",
"optional": true,
"field": "ts_ms"
},
{
"type": "struct",
"fields": [
{
"type": "string",
"optional": false,
"field": "id"
},
{
"type": "int64",
"optional": false,
"field": "total_order"
},
{
"type": "int64",
"optional": false,
"field": "data_collection_order"
}
],
"optional": true,
"field": "transaction"
}
],
"optional": false,
"name": "test.public.test.Envelope"
},
"payload": {
"before": null,
"after": {
"id": 4441,
"test_c_id": 3606,
"test_b_c": "QWERTY",
"test_a_t": null,
"test_p": [
"qwe",
"asd",
"zxc"
],
"test_d_id": 22827
},
"source": {
"version": "1.2.2.Final",
"connector": "postgresql",
"name": "test",
"ts_ms": 1599543319277,
"snapshot": "false",
"db": "test",
"schema": "public",
"table": "test",
"txId": 3914206,
"lsn": 108940649328,
"xmin": null
},
"op": "u",
"ts_ms": 1599543319509,
"transaction": null
}
}

Ex:

```
Kafka                  Sink DB
---------------------------------------
test_c_id: 3606        test_c_id: 22632
test_b_c: QWERTY       test_b_c: null
```

Around 5-10% of data have mismatch, and all of them occur only in 2 columns out of 20.

Does anyone know what could cause such an issue?

Comment: How do you know you are comparing the correct messages? For example, is there some other data where `test_c_id=22632` that was upserted after `test_c_id=3606`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer by looking for messages with specific `"id": XXXX`. I mean I'm pretty sure that I'm looking at correct messages

Comment: Also I created a second sink connector only with one topic, and it works just file. Data inside db as expected, even though they both read from the same topic

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with your `RegexRouter` setup that is overwriting some data between multiple topics

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, seems like the issue was because of `RegexRouter`